# Kube Proxy - IPVS proxier will not be used because the following required kernel modules are not loaded: [ip_vs_wrr ip_vs_sh]

Tags: kubernetes, kube-proxy

I have setup Kubernetes 1.15 cluster on CentOS 7.6 server using IPVS. when I reboot the server kube-proxy changing to  iptables mode. If I run `modprobe -a ip_vs ip_vs_rr ip_vs_wrr ip_vs_sh nf_conntrack_ipv4` command and restart the kube-proxy on that node kube-proxy starting in IPVS mode.

What is the best way to fix this issue during the reboot?

Thanks

SR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mark the required modules to load at boot time, automatically?

You can edit the file `/etc/modules` (or create a new file in `/etc/modules-load.d`) containing names of required ones

```
ip_vs
ip_vs_rr
ip_vs_wrr
ip_vs_sh
nf_conntrack_ipv4
```

Comment: Thanks, created file `/etc/modules-load.d/ipvs.conf` and rebooted the machine. it worked.